# Spawning multiple robots each with a controller in the same namespace as the controller_manager

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a problem when trying to start controllers for multiple robots that they cannot find the controller_manager

```
[WARN] [1498038782.062813, 84.949000]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
```

I am using the plugin in the .xacro file like so:

```
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

and then launching each robot in a group with a different namespace.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16497/spawning-multiple-robots-each-with-a-controller-in-the-same-namespace-as-the-controller_manager/) by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Minutes after posting this question I managed to resolve it:

First of all you have to remove the namespace tag from the .xacro/urdf file in order for the robots to get a namespece you specify, like so:

```
 <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

Second, you have to specify the namespace almost everywhere even if you have the group tag, and I'll give an example for one robot:

```
<group ns="/robot1">
  <param name="tf_prefix" value="atlas1" />
   <rosparam file="$(find YOUR_PACKAGE)/config/control.yaml" command="load" ns="/robot1" /> 
   <param name="/robot1/robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)"/>
      <node name="urdf_spawner_1" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="-z 1.0 -unpause -urdf -model robot1 -param robot_description " respawn="false" output="screen">
      </node>

      <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"  name="robot_state_publisher_1">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />
      </node>

      <node name="robot1_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" 
        args="--namespace=/robot1
        joint_state_controller
        tri_wheel_controller
        arm_controller
        --shutdown-timeout 3">
      </node>

      <node name="rqt_robot_steering1" pkg="rqt_robot_steering" type="rqt_robot_steering">
        <param name="default_topic" value="/robot1/tri_wheel_controller/cmd_vel"/>
      </node>
  </group>
```

And so on for another robot.
Keep in mind that i redefined the **robot_description** each time in order for the controller to find it in the same namespace. It didn't work for me to define it outside and the use it in the group like **/robot_description**

**tf_prefix** is used in order to see all the robots in rviz. I am not sure how does it work without it, or how to use something else as tf_prefix is deprecated. For now it does not work to see it in rviz so I figures it does not calculate the tf for the link. I don't know how to solve this

---

Originally posted by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) with karma: 41 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DangTran](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24992/dangtran/) on 2020-03-27**:
Wonderful, this  works well for me. For anyone in the same problem, `control.yaml` should remove the robot namespace (first line of the yaml), if multiple robots have same configuration.